# Prevent Image in ImageView from being resized when dragged out of RelativeLayout

Tags: image, resize, imageview

I didn't find the answer to my question in the other topics.

I have an ImageView with a background drawable. This ImageView has an onTouchListener on it and one can drag it around. I now want to add an ImageResource to this view (together with a padding). The Image should be always in the middle of the (square) ImageView. The problem is now: If I drag the whole ImageView out of the display, the Image in the ImageView begins to shrink/resize. When I drag it back into the window, it starts to grow again up to the size, which is allowed (since there is a padding).

How can i prevent this image from being resized, when dragged out of the window?

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
ImageView i = new ImageView(this);
i.setPadding(10);
i.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
i.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg));
i.setPositionAndSize(0, 0); // creates layout params and positions
                            // it with margins in relative layout
i.setOnTouchListener(touch);
layout.addView(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

If this Relative layout has WrapContent Property on layout_width or height, those properties will change dynamically.

When you add a View, you are modifying its content, and so on those properties.

You need to set the layout properties to this imageView like this. The positionAndSize you want to set, must be set in the properties of layout params:

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lyp = new  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
ImageView i = new ImageView(this);
            (the properties you want the parent of the view (layout) to receive must be setted here in "lyp"). 
i.setLayoutParams(lyp);
layout.addView(i,lyp);
```

Remember that if you are add something over Relative Layout, those properties are necessary.

Relative layouts are desgined to fit content to FIXED heights and Widths so try to fix those properties in layout.

Hope did help!!